# Linux bash error comando cut

Tags: linux

Tengo el siguiente código en un script bash

```
LANG=$(echo es_file.txt | cut -d _ -f 1)
   echo $LANG
```

Da un error "cut: orden no encontrada"

He probado diferentes opciones:

```
LANG=$(echo 'es_file.txt' | cut -d _ -f 1)
   echo $LANG
LANG=$('echo es_file.txt | cut -d _ -f 1')
   echo $LANG
```

Pero siempre obtengo el mismo error. He verificado que tengo el comando cut instalado en mi máquina Ubuntu 20.4.
¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que se imprima el contenido del archivo `es_file.txt` para pasarlo por el `cut`, no se usa `echo` sino `cat`.

Comment: No, lo que pretendo es que imprima "es" omitiendo el resto del nombre del archivo. Es decir variable LANG=es

Comment: Creo que en un script no tiene un $PATH%.  Ha intentado con /usr/bin/cut (o qualquier ubicación tiene)?

Comment: Borra esta linea `LANG=$('echo es_file.txt | cut -d _ -f 1')` porque es la que hace que aparezca el error... la otra deberia funcionarte bien

Comment: @masterguru, ninguna de tres funciona y sólo utilizo una, simplemente las he puesto para que vean las pruebas que he realizado

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona de todas las formas excepto la que he indicado antes.  ¿Usas Shebang?  ¿Como ejecutas el script desde la linea de comandos?  Haz un `echo $PATH` tambien antes de llamar a ese comando, para ver que rutas tienes, no sea que ahi este el problema, como te han dicho antes

Comment: Mil gracias por vuestra ayuda, efectivamente se trataba de un error en $PATH